# Wordpress navigation link menu issue

Tags: wordpress

I am facing a problem with my wordpress site.
I configured the drop down navigation menu.But after clicking on the contents of the menu my page doesn't redirect to the destination page.Although the url in the address bar changes according to the selected option,but I need to explicitly refresh the page to display that page
can anyone please suggest on this.

Comment: This sounds like a corrupt cache &/or erronous JS / AJAX. Show us some code or post a link to the relevant page(s) so we can take a look.